# how to convert a text into tuples in a list in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am a beginner in python and desperately need someone's help.

I am trying to convert a text into tuples in a list.
The original text was already tokenized and each pos was tagged as below:

```
The/DT Fulton/NNP County/NNP Grand/NNP Jury/NNP said/VBD Friday/NNP an/DT
```

And the desired output looks as below:

```
[('The', 'DT'), ('Fulton', 'NNP'), ('County', 'NNP'), ...)]
```

So, if anyone can offer me a help, it would be so awesome!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like below:

```
>>> s = 'The/DT Fulton/NNP County/NNP Grand/NNP Jury/NNP said/VBD Friday/NNP an/DT'
>>> 
>>> [tuple(i.split('/')) for i in s.split()]
[('The', 'DT'), ('Fulton', 'NNP'), ('County', 'NNP'), ('Grand', 'NNP'), ('Jury', 'NNP'), ('said', 'VBD'), ('Friday', 'NNP'), ('an', 'DT')]
```

[`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) is used to form a list of strings using *space* separator in the first time and *slash* in the second time (to split each sub-item to two elements)

[`tuple()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-tuple) is used to transform each sub-item (which contains two elements) to a `tuple`.

Comment: like the pythonic way

Answer (score 1):

```
x="The/DT Fulton/NNP County/NNP Grand/NNP Jury/NNP said/VBD Friday/NNP an/DT"
print re.findall(r"(\w+)\/(\w+)", x)
```

Output:

`[('The', 'DT'), ('Fulton', 'NNP'), ('County', 'NNP'), ('Grand', 'NNP'), ('Jury', 'NNP'), ('said', 'VBD'), ('Friday', 'NNP'), ('an', 'DT')]`

Comment: @Sophia do accept any one of the answers by clicking the green arrow