# Counting values in a list in python

Tags: python, tuples

I'm a beginner in python and having a hard time figuring out what the problem is with my code.

What i'm trying to do here is to convert a text into tuples in a list and then count the number of DTs in the list.

let's say the first three lines of the txt file looks below:

```
The/DT Fulton/NNP County/NNP Grand/NNP Jury/NNP said/VBD Friday/NNP an/DT investigation/NN of/IN Atlanta/NNP 's/POS recent/JJ primary/JJ election/NN produced/VBD ``/`` no/DT evidence/NN ''/'' that/IN any/DT irregularities/NNS took/VBD place/NN ./. 
The/DT jury/NN further/RB said/VBD in/IN term-end/JJ presentments/NNS that/IN the/DT City/NNP Executive/NNP Committee/NNP ,/, which/WDT had/VBD over-all/JJ charge/NN of/IN the/DT election/NN ,/, ``/`` deserves/VBZ the/DT praise/NN and/CC thanks/NNS of/IN the/DT City/NNP of/IN Atlanta/NNP ''/'' for/IN the/DT manner/NN in/IN which/WDT the/DT election/NN was/VBD conducted/VBN ./.
The/DT September-October/NNP term/NN jury/NN had/VBD been/VBN charged/VBN by/IN Fulton/NNP Superior/NNP Court/NNP Judge/NNP Durwood/NNP Pye/NNP to/TO investigate/VB reports/NNS of/IN possible/JJ ``/`` irregularities/NNS ''/'' in/IN the/DT hard-fought/JJ primary/NN which/WDT was/VBD won/VBN by/IN Mayor-nominate/NNP Ivan/NNP Allen/NNP Jr./NNP ./.
```

This was saved as "practice.txt" in the workspace.

So my code looks as below:

```
with open("practice.txt") as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        cnt += 1
        word = line.split()
        total_word_per_line += len(word)
        total_type_of_words += len(set(word))
        a = [tuple(i.split('/')) for i in word]

    for x in a:
        DT_sum = 0
        if x[1] == 'DT':
            DT_sum += 1

        total_DT_sum += DT_sum

    print total_DT_sum
```

But the output shows 2 for total_DT_sum, which means it only counted DTs in the third list. Any suggestion to count all DTs?

The desired output is 5(total number of DT from the three sentences above)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You set `DT_sum` to 0 at the start of every iteration. You should move that initialisation to before the loop.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but should'nt the `DT_sum = 0` be before the `for x in a:` line?

Comment: there are 13 `/DT` strings in your 3 sentences.

Comment: Is this a [homework question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41259747/how-to-convert-a-text-into-tuples-in-a-list-in-python) or something? This is the 3rd time I've seen this question this morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is required to store your data in a list of tuples before counting the number of `'DT'`, you can use [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) like this:

```
my_list = []

with open('practice.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        my_list.extend([tuple(i.split('/')) for i in line.split()])

res = filter(lambda i: i[1] == 'DT', my_list)
print(len(res))  # Output: 13
```

[`extend()`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) is used to add each line's constructed tuples to `my_list`

[`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) will return only items with `'DT'` in the second position.

**Output:**

```
>>> res = filter(lambda i: i[1] == 'DT', my_list)
>>> res
[('The', 'DT'), ('an', 'DT'), ('no', 'DT'), ('any', 'DT'), ('The', 'DT'), ('the', 'DT'), ('the', 'DT'), ('the', 'DT'), ('the', 'DT'), ('the', 'DT'), ('the', 'DT'), ('The', 'DT'), ('the', 'DT')]
>>>
>>> len(res)
13
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error:

```
for x in a:
    DT_sum = 0
```

`DT_sum` is reset to 0 each time...

In case you want to do it from scratch, the simplest way to do it would be with a `sum` of the `count` on each line:

```
with open("practice.txt") as myfile:
    nb_dt = sum(line.count("/DT") for line in my_file)
```

result is 13, not 5 as you stated (which can be manually verified)

That solution does not take into consideration word split. It means that it will find `/DTXXX` as well if there are some.

So a little more complex code does that:

```
with open("practice.txt") as myfile:
    nb_dt = sum(1 if word.partition("/")[2]=="DT" else 0 for line in my_file for word in line.split())
```

Counts 1 for each time splitting according to `/` has `DT` on its right for each word of each line.